# Visual FoxPro DB don't have program need to convert to something else

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have inherited a database that was created in Visual FoxPro.  I don't have that program.  Currently I have Access 2007.  I've been trying to get External Data using an VFPOLEDB file that I got from the Microsoft website.  When I try to use it with Microsoft Query its not listed.  I used the Setup Installer Package.  Do I need to put it somewhere special?  Its in the common files\system\ole DB folder.  Along with all of the other .dll files.

I'm at my wits end.  Keep in mind I don't have the VFP program.  If this is why I'm failing please yell at me.  Then I'll know all is lost and I can just quit my job and become a hobo.

Comment: What do you need to do with your DB? View the data? Export it? Load to server DB?

Comment: Do you have the 64-bit version of MS Access by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ODBC driver instead see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx